# Empty constructor in FeedReaderContract demo

Tags: java, android

Referring to the `FeedReaderContract` class on Android Developers page:

- [Saving Data in SQL Databases](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

The code starts as:

```
public final class FeedReaderContract {
    // To prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the contract class,
    // give it an empty constructor.
    public FeedReaderContract() {}
```

i.e. there is a default `public` constructor for the class.

- **Is that code comment correct?**
- How does a `public` empty constructor prevent instantiation - should this maybe be `private`?

---

... am I still half asleep ? ...

---

PS I'm not concerned about the rest of the example, or how to use it. I am purely trying to confirm that I'm not going mad and stupid at the same time...

Comment: Yup, you are right. It should be private of course.

Comment: Try instantiating it.

Comment: dunno if there is any point leaving this question up - but maybe it will help a beginner who is confused by that code, so I've self-answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Self answer because this may help beginners?

The code comment is wrong. Empty constructor works fine.

To prevent instantiation, the constructor needs to be `private`, not empty.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it with the following two classes and the comment indeed is wrong. Only a private constructor will prevent instantiating.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        System.out.println(Test.STRING);
        System.out.println(test.toString());
    }
}

public final class Test {
    public static final String STRING = "test";

    // empty constructor:
     private Test() {
    }
}
```